# User-defined function call vs calling UDF in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user-defined function that is called inside a stored procedure. All that stored procedure does is return the value that is obtained from the UDF scalar function.

However:

```
SELECT * UDF_FunctionName(param1,param2)
```

udf call is here:

```
SELECT dbo.udfFunction('1234', 10) AS result
```

and

```
Exec StoredProcName(param1, param2)
```

are returning different results.

`StoredProcName` calls the `UDF_FunctionName(param1, param2)`

This is the stored procedure code:

```
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    RETURN SELECT [DbName].[dbo].[udfFunction](@param1, @param2) 
END
```

What could be the reason for different results?

Comment: This will definately need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: We need to see what the results are as well as the code if you are legally allowed to show it.

Comment: What are your results/how do they differ between the function's results and the stored procedure's results?

Comment: Ya I am not allowed to show it legally. its just returning a true or false. But from a sql perspective is there any difference between the two statements?. Apologize not being able to give more info.

Comment: The sproc returns false, the UDF function call returns true.

Comment: You dont need to show us your actual code! You need to show us an example of how to reproduce the issue. Otherwise this is unanswerable.

Comment: Why do you have a stored proc that does nothing but call a scalar function? Can you convert that scalar function into something better? Scalar functions are notoriously poor from a performance perspective.

Comment: SELECT dbo.udfFunction('1234',10) as result                                       and                                                                                                               the sproc returns this                                                                                      BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 Return SELECT [DbName].[dbo].[udfFunction](@UserName, @EntityID)
 
END

Comment: Update your question! Dont make us read code in a comment!!

Comment: The function is being called via  DAL in a web app. they have it done that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `RETURN` and `SELECT` together:

```
Return SELECT [DbName].[dbo].[udfFunction](@param1, @param2)
```

You cannot do that, you either want to return the result, or select it. Depending on which you choose, retrieving the value will differ.

If you do this:

```
SELECT [DbName].[dbo].[udfFunction](@param1, @param2)
```

Then the *resultset* will have a single row and column containing your value. Access this exactly as you would any other resultset.

If you do this:

```
RETURN [DbName].[dbo].[udfFunction](@param1, @param2)
```

Your stored procedure will have a *return value* which is the result of your function call. Access this by defining a scalar variable and assigning it to the result of the SP call - assuming the result is `INT` that might look like

```
DECLARE @result INT
EXEC @Result = StoredProcName(@param1, @param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `RETURN` in this way in a stored procedure. If you want to return a scalar value to the calling code use an [`OUTPUT` parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx). `RETURN` is [generally used for status codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx).

You might have something like

```
-- SAMPLE UDF
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourUDF (@Username VARCHAR(30), @EntityID INT)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @EntityID;
END
GO
-- SAMPLE PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc @Username VARCHAR(30), @EntityID INT, @Output INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @Output = dbo.YourUDF(@Username, @EntityID);

    IF @Output IS NULL -- AN ERROR
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1; -- RETURN A STATUS OF -1 TO INDICATE ERROR
    END 

END
```

Then you could call this as:

```
DECLARE @Output INT, @ReturnValue INT;

EXECUTE @ReturnValue = dbo.YourProc 
                            @Username = '1234', 
                            @EntityID = 1, 
                            @Output = @Output OUTPUT;

SELECT  ValueFromUDF = @Output,
        ReturnValue = @ReturnValue;
```

This returns:

```
ValueFromUDF    ReturnValue
------------------------------
    1               0
```

If we pass `NULL` as @EntityID, to trigger the artificial error, then we get a return status of -1:

```
DECLARE @Output INT, @ReturnValue INT;

EXECUTE @ReturnValue = dbo.YourProc 
                            @Username = '1234', 
                            @EntityID = NULL, 
                            @Output = @Output OUTPUT;

SELECT  ValueFromUDF = @Output,
        ReturnValue = @ReturnValue;

ValueFromUDF    ReturnValue
------------------------------
    NULL            1
```